# что-то странное с телефоном XIAOMI

Tags: linux

После перезагрузки появился значок Linux и больше ничего не происходит — черный экран и посередине этот значок. 
Извините, что не по теме программирования, просто, может, кто-то знает что это.

Comment: извинения не спасут...сча заминусуют по полной

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите как [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMZ08qQrqnc) или [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJ4wW9-69_s) телефоны возвращают к жизни. Вроде и без слов понятно)

Можете поискать и другие ресурсы и видео по ключевым словам `Penguin logo xiaomi`, такая проблема встречается давно.

P.S Я не знаток в этом деле, и всего лишь нашел для вас источники для самостоятельного решения проблемы. 
Так как это не софт, то помните, что все, что вы делаете - делаете на свой страх и риск и ответственны за проблемы только вы.

Но сильно перед экзекуцией не переживайте, это вредит делу)